# Are folding poles suitable for cross-country skiing?

Tags: gear, cross-country-skiing

There are several manufacturers selling folding/collapsible poles, usually for hiking or splitboarding. Are they also suitable for cross-country skiing?

Comment: AFter giving this question more thought I realized that unless you could collapse your skis then there's little advantage to having collapsible poles. For hiking the poles are the longest thing, for split-boarding you want the poles out of the way, but for cross-country, you're still going to always have those long skis.

Comment: Funny you should mention it, I asked this question too: 
http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/3678/2064 
Unfortunately the migration to this site deleted the previous answers (but they weren't a perfect solution anyway).

Comment: @furtive: There are actually some advantages for adjustable poles: If you can also put on different baskets and/or tips, you could use them for alpine skiing and/or nordic walking. Plus you could lend them to someone else who has a different height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't any x-country specific adjustable poles because there are no real benefits.

- The skis will always be longer than the poles.
- Unlike hiking or splitboarding, scenarios where you need to stow the poles but not the skis don't exist for x-country skiing.
- It adds weight in a sport where weight is a big factor.
- Unlike hiking and skiing, [double polling](http://www.nordicskiracer.com/news.asp?NewsID=5030), where maximum force is applied to poles, means the risk of poles collapsing (losing length) is significant and detrimental to performance.
- A single shaft will transfer more force than a double shaft.

Currently available collapsible poles are [mostly too short](http://www.nordicskiersports.com/xc-ski-pole-sizing-chart.html) for the long stroke necessary in cross-country skiing, and probably wouldn't stand up well to hours of double polling.

Comment: That's a good point about double polling. As for the length, I have seen collapsible poles (also from BD) that extend up to 155cm, thought that's still too short for the tallest skiers. And I know little of the reliability, especially when extended to full length.

Comment: For rollerskiing there would be an advantage as it would be much easier to transport rollerskis + poles + boots.

Comment: Decathlon is now selling collapsible cross-country ski poles (only for casual skiers): https://www.decathlon.co.uk/p/adult-cross-country-adjustable-ski-pole-xc-s-150/_/R-p-306304